# Nginx respond only to localhost: but not to server_name

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, vmware

While discovering nginx (using this tutor https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ubuntu-18-04-ru) met a trouble on the "Step 5 – Setting Up Server Blocks (Recommended)". Here is my server block file.

```
server {
       listen 81;
       listen [::]:81;

       root /var/www/tutorial;
       index index.html;
       server_name example.ubuntu.com;
       location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }
}
```

But nginx response only for `localhost:81` query, not to [example.ubuntu.com](http://example.ubuntu.com)

Comment: Because you're telling it to listen on port 81.

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I get the response from server by my domain name. Problem was in my incompetence. I was blindly follow the aforementioned tutorial that has no steps about additional configuration of "hosts" file. That exactly was the only necessary step...